# How to get request headers in python scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

How to get request headers in python scrapy for a dynamic table data?

The request is made when a button is clicked.

Is there is a way to get the data without using click simulation?

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the request from the website using the browser network tab. Observe the network tab to check which request is made when the button is clicked.

After that you can make the same request to the API in scrapy using the `Request` class.

Something like this:

```
yield scrapy.Request("http://www.example.com/some_page.html",
                     headers={'header', 'value'},
                     callback=self.parse_table
                    )
```

More info on `Request` [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request)

Comment: I checked it via `Network Tab` but the it has a different url and the page url doesn't change

Comment: When making an ajax request, the page url doesn't change, what you need to do is to send the request to that url which is displayed in the network tab in scrapy using the method I mentioned above. In that way you will get the same data in your spider.